# How find the min element of a nested list and return its siblings, and its parents Ids

Tags: c#, list, performance, linq

**Problem description:**

I have a scenario of List of `Manufacturers` each contain a `ManufacturerId` and a nested list of `Products`, which contain a `ProductId` and a nested list of `Qualities`, which contain a `QualityId` and a `Price`.

```
--Manufacturers (List) 
----ManufacturerId (string)
----Products (List)
------ProductId (string)
------Qualities (List) 
    -QualityId (string)
    -Price (decimal)
```

Or

```
class Manufacturer { string ManufacturerId { get; set; } IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; } }
class Product { string ProductId { get; set; } IEnumerable<Quality> Qualities { get; set; } }
class Quality { string QualityId { get; set; } decimal Price { get; set; } }
```

**My goal:**

Choose one manufacture and one product, and build a list of its chosen product's qualities `List<string>` where each item is a key constructed by  `$"{ManufacturerId}-{ProductId}-{QualityId}"` key.

How to choose the manufacture and product:

1. Prioritized by the products from all the manufacturers with order by a `string[] ProductPriotizeList
   => new[] { "P1", "P8", "P5", "P2" ... };`
2. Ordered by cheapest price and get its `QualityId`.
3. Construct the `List<string>` keys of `$"{ManufacturerId}-{ProductId}-{QualityId}"` by the selected `QualityId` siblings (Note that the each of the selected keys will have the same ManufacturerId and ProductId and only vary by QualityId).

**I tried (and it working):**

I've created a class called `FlattenQuality` contain the `Quality` properties and added the `ManufacturerId` and the `ProductId` to it (by looping each of the manufacturers and each of the products).

```
class FlattenQuality 
{ 
    string QualityId { get; set; }
    string ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    string ProductId { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    string Key { get { return $"{ManufacturerId}-{ProductId}-{QualityId}"; }
}
```

Then constructed a list of `FlattenQuality` by `SelectMany` over the manufacturers and `SelectMany` over the products:

```
List<FlattenQuality> flattenQualities = BuildFlattenQuality(..);
```

Then the resulted selected keys list:

```
List<string> selected = flattenQualities.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(ProductPriotizeList, x.ProductId)).ThenBy(x => x.Price).Select(x => x.MyKey).ToList();
```

For Example:

```
{
    "Manufacturers": [
    {
        "ManufacturerId": 1,
        "Products": [
        {
            "ProductId": P1,
            "Qualities": [
            {
                "QualityId": 1,
                "Price": 10
            },
            {
                "QualityId": 2,
                "Price": 20
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "ManufacturerId": 2,
        "Products": [
        {
            "ProductId": P1,
            "Qualities": [
            {
                "QualityId": 1,
                "Price": 15
            },
            {
                "QualityId": 2,
                "Price": 30
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Output should be:

```
{
    "Keys": [
        "1-1-1", //The QualityId 1 of productId 1 of ManuId 1 is the cheapest
        "2-1-1"  //The cheapest sibling
    ]
}
```

**My Question:**

How to achieve the same result of selected keys without to pollute my app with additional model? and without iterating all of the list again.

Comment: By using anonymous type?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski not sure how to do it...

Comment: It would be immensly helpgul if you could provide examples of a given input and an expected output. Also, the hierarchy you present at the beginning of the question doesn't seem to fit the textual description, which says: *"[...] nested list of `Qualities`, which contain a `QualityId` **and a nested list of `Manufacturers`**"* - so I exepcted that a `Quality` to have a nestd `Manufacturers`, but it doesn't.

Comment: Hey @HeyJude thanks for the insight, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is flatten your data. To do that:

```
var records = 
    manufacturers.SelectMany(m => 
        m.Products.SelectMany(p =>
            p.Qualities.Select(q => new 
            { 
                ManufacturerId = m.ManufacturerId,
                ProductId = p.ProductId, 
                QualityId = q.QualityId, 
                Price = q.Price,
                Key = string.Join("-", new string [] {m.ManufacturerId, p.ProductId, q.QualityId })
            })
        )
    );
```

Then apply your ordering logic:

```
records.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(productPriotizeList, x.ProductId))
       .ThenBy(x => x.Price);
```

See a working demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RXYBI).

Comment: Thank! See the updated question, I've updated the output example